# having trouble updating a column name in sqlite, with a variable in Python 3

Tags: python, sql-update

## having trouble updating a column name in sqlite, with a variable in Python 3

it selects the corect column but won't do the update

```
colToEdit = input('Which COL do you want to edit?: ')
if colToEdit == '1':
  newvalue = input('What is the new name?: ')
  c.execute("UPDATE cards SET ccname = ?", newvalue "WHERE ROWID=?",cardToEdit);
```

**Error**
c.execute("UPDATE cards SET ccname = ?", newvalue "WHERE ROWID=?",cardToEdit);

Comment: try this c.execute("UPDATE cards SET ccname = {}, WHERE ROWID={}".fromat(newvalue,ardToEdit));

Comment: thank you for answering. i got it with this: c.execute("UPDATE cards SET name = ? WHERE ROWID=?",(newvalue, cardToEdit)); where name is the name of the column